# Wagtail: How to overwrite create/edit template for PageModel

Tags: python, wagtail

I want to overwrite `create.html` and `edit.html` used for models derived from Wagtails 'PageModel'.

If I understand the [docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html?highlight=templates#overriding-templates) correctly it should be as simple as specifying the attributes:

```
class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = MyPage
    create_template_name = "myapp/create.html" 
    edit_template_name = "myapp/edit.html"
```

My templates are located at `projectroot/templates/myapp`. It works fine if my model is a Django model but for a `PageModel` based model the create view still uses `wagtailadmin/pages/create.html`. I also tried the other location patterns mentioned in the docs w/o success.

Is it possible to change the edit and create templates for a `PageModel`? Or do the same limitations as for views apply, i.e. only `index.html` and `inspect.html` can be overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelAdmin` does not provide create, edit, or delete functionality for Page models, as per the [documentation note](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html).

> NOTE: modeladmin only provides ‘create’, ‘edit’ and ‘delete’ functionality for non page type models (i.e. models that do not extend wagtailcore.models.Page). If your model is a ‘page type’ model, customising any of the following will not have any effect.

It can be a bit confusing as the `ModelAdmin` system would seem to work for page models also, but there are some other ways to modify how your page can be edited. These will not be scoped to the `ModelAdmin` area though.

### Option 1 - customise the generated form for your `MyPage` model

- If you only want to customise how the edit page **form** that gets generated you can modify the `base_form_class` on your page model.
- Wagtail has documentation about [how to create a custom page form](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#customising-generated-forms).
- Note: `WagtailAdminPageForm` extends [Django's ModelFormMetaClass](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/forms/models/)

Example

```py
from django import forms
from django.db import models

from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm
from wagtail.core.models import Page


class EventPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):
      # ...


class MyPage(Page):
    # ...
    base_form_class = MyPageForm
```

### Option 2 - customise the view via hooks

To customise the create & edit views for the normal (e.g. clicking edit page on the Wagtail user bar or explorer) page editing interface, you will need to use [Wagtail hooks](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html). Here you have access to the request so you will likely be able to determine if you are in the `ModelAdmin` area.

Create a file called `wagtail_hooks.py` in your app folder and provide a  hook that will return a custom response (this will need to be rendered by your custom view.).

There are separate hooks for `before_create_page` and `before_edit_page`

Example from [`before_create_page` docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#before-create-page) below.

````py
from wagtail.core import hooks

from .models import AwesomePage
from .admin_views import edit_awesome_page

@hooks.register('before_create_page')
def before_create_page(request, parent_page, page_class):
    # Use a custom create view for the AwesomePage model
    if page_class == AwesomePage:
        return create_awesome_page(request, parent_page)
```python
````

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer. Option 1 it is. I thought I was missing something because the docs explicitly state overriding views is not possible for Page models and the same example for overriding templates does not mention the impossibility. "`create_template_name` to specify a template for CreateView" vs. "`create_view_class` (not used for ‘page type’ models)

Comment: Yeah, I can see how it can be confusing, feel free to raise an issue or PR on the Wagtail repo and suggest a better way this can be communicated. Hope the rest of your project goes well.